# Install Openssl 1.0.2 fail on fedora release 21

Tags: linux, openssl, fedora-21

I'm trying to install openssl 1.0.2 on Fedora 21 follow steps:

1. ./config
2. make
3. make test
4. make install

I got error in step 3:

> ```
> CMS consistency test
> /bin/perl cms-test.pl
> CMS => PKCS#7 compatibility tests
> signed content DER format, RSA key: verify error
> Makefile:314: recipe for target 'test_cms' failed
> make[1]: *** [test_cms] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/l3/Desktop/Lib3rd/openssl-1.0.2-stable-SNAP-20121003/test'
> Makefile:456: recipe for target 'tests' failed
> make: *** [tests] Error 2
> ```

Please help me,

Thanks,

Comment: `openssl-1.0.2-stable-SNAP-20121003`: where did you get your OpenSSL from? This appears to be nearly 6 years old!?

Comment: T1412: The source package `openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.src.rpm` was updated a month ago. ( Generally Enterprise packages get all new security fixes.) Rebuild with `$ rpmbuild --rebuild openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.src.rpm` to create the Fedora packages. http://vault.centos.org/7.5.1804/os/Source/SPackages/openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.src.rpm

Comment: Matt Caswell: I get it from http://193.166.3.2/pub/unix/security/tools/CERT-dfn-tools/net/openssl/snapshot/
Because my software require this version. Anyway, I'll install new version and check whether it's compatible with my software